# Clopens of a sub-Stone space

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a Stone space and $T$ a sub-Stone space, i.e. a closed subset of $S$ with the subspace topology.

**Question:** is each clopen subset $U$ of $T$ of the form $U = V \cap T$ where $V$ is clopen in $S$?

I started doubting this because we may have some closed $V' \subset S$ such that $U = V' \cap T$ and an open $V'' \subset S$ such that $U = V'' \cap T$ such that $V' \neq V''$. I see no easy argument why there must be a single clopen witness $V \subset S$ then proves that $U$ is both open and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a small argument:

Let $C$ be clopen in $T$. For each $x \in C$ pick some clopen subset $C_x$ of $S$ such that $x \in C_x \cap T \subseteq C$. This can be done as $C$ is open in $T$ and clopen sets are a base of $S$.

Then finitely many $C_x \cap C$ cover $C$ as $C$ is closed (hence compact).
So say $C \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^n (C_{x_i} \cap T)$ for finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.
Then $C' = \cup_{i=1}^n C_{x_i}$ is a clopen subset of $S$ such that $C' \cap T = C$ as required.

Comment: I was just reading your reference, but this argument is even simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @MathStudent020 The [notes](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csulrich/ftp/MatthewGwynne1208.pdf) don't really prove it explicitly I think but they do offer a nice and standard write-up.

Comment: And [here](http://aw.twi.tudelft.nl/~hart/personal-english.html) you can find (under teaching) some good notes on Boolean algebras written by a topologist.

Comment: [direct link to previous](http://aw.twi.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/onderwijs/old-courses/boole.pdf) see p6, n5 for a relevant exercise.